# ArgumentError: Mapper mapped class Users->users could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table 'users'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am new to SQLAlchemy. Trying to build database in Heroku Postgres

Get error:
**ArgumentError: Mapper mapped class Users->users could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table 'users'**

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import (Column, Integer, BigInteger, String, Sequence, TIMESTAMP, Boolean, JSON)
from sqlalchemy import sql
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, String, MetaData, Sequence, create_engine
```

```py
class Users(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'users'
    
    meta = MetaData()
    
    users_table = Table(
    'users', meta,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('name',String(50)),
    Column('fullname',String(50)),
    Column('phone',Integer),
               )
       
    meta.create_all(engine)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<User(id='{}', fullname='{}', username='{}')>".format(
            self.id, self.full_name, self.username)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reasons this does not work is that you try to create the table before the class `User` is created AND also the table you declare is not declared on the correct attribute.  So sqlalchemy cannot find the id column.
I have tried to outline a more idiomatic declarative approach below:

```py
# This implicitly creates metadata, you do not need to make an explicit one.
Base = declarative_base()

class Users(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'users'
    
    # Using a table explicitly is not required here
    # Just declare the columns as properties.
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50))
    fullname = Column(String(50))
    phone = Column(Integer)
       
    # Don't do this here because Users is not done 
    # meta.create_all(engine)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<User(id='{}', fullname='{}', username='{}')>".format(
            self.id, self.full_name, self.username)

# Do this after classes are declared and use Base's metadata.
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

References:

If you really want to set a table you have to set it with `__table__` and use `Base.metadata`:
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/declarative/table_config.html#using-a-hybrid-approach-with-table